# Где хранить переменные окружения в manjaro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, archlinux, manjaro

В ubuntu и её производных я могу например хранить переменные env в /etc/environment. Тогда когда я запускаю графическое приложение не через консоль, то переменные подхватываются. Но в manjaro и вроде в archlinux нет этого файла /etc/environment. Где нужно хранить переменные окружения?

Comment: а что вам мешает использовать упомянутый файл?

Comment: в моей манджаре есть этот файл (хотя я им не пользуюсь, подключаю всё что мне нужно в `~/.bashrc`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буду краток. `man environment.d` расскажет в каких файлах могут лежать переменные с их значениями и даже какие модули systemd отвечают за обработку этих файлов:

```
~/.config/environment.d/*.conf
/etc/environment.d/*.conf
/run/environment.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/environment.d/*.conf
/etc/environment
```

Вообще, неплохо помогает применение утилиты `apropos` в поиске ответов на вопросы. Например: `apropos environment`

Answer (score 3):

На системном уровне всё так же, если файла нет создайте.

```
/etc/profile
/etc/environment
```

На пользовательском, на уровне юзера приоритетней.

```
~/.profile
~/.pam_environment
```

Конечно же `~/.bashrc` и даже `~/.xinitrc`.